# sudo-apt get update stuck 0% at my router's ip address

Tags: networking, apt, updates, internet

```
smartmeet@Anonymus:~$ sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.1)] [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.
0% [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.1)] [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.
0% [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.1)] [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.
0% [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.1)] [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.
0% [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.1)] [Connecting to 172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.
```

172.16.3.1 is my router's IP address.

Comment: Does your router use some sort of firewall ?

Comment: Can you mention what you have tried.

Comment: Does your system running behind the proxy?

Comment: No my router doesn't use any sort  of firewall! @Serg

Comment: All the methods available in threads like (1)sudo-apt get clean (2)disabling the IPv6

Comment: no proxy of any type is there @Thushi

Comment: @MeetShah OK, in that case open System Settings -> Software and Updates , and change "Download from" to some other server. See if that works

Comment: I have tried that,too! but unfortunately it didn't help me! @Serg

Comment: very peculiar. I will put bounty on your question, maybe someone can figure it out

Comment: Can you please run something like `traceroute google.com` and show the output?

Comment: also can you post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: and can you additionally post the output of `sudo grep -Ri proxy /etc/apt/{preferences.d,apt.conf.d}/`, please

Comment: I've had an issue like this before. You probably have a dns problem. Try to change it to google or opendns. Make sure your router can connect to the internet

Comment: Does this happen with sudo apt-get install also ?

Comment: Can give the output of: ip a ip route cat /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Can you ping your router at 172.16.3.1? If that is ok, can you ping google? What are your dns servers, can you paste the contents of /etc/resolv.conf, or run 'nmcli c' to get the name of your connection and then run 'nm c s <connection name> | grep dns' and paste the output? Can other pcs connect to the Internet through that router? If you log into the router, can it ping google? Please answer all questions and use pastebin.com and provide links to show your command output please?

Comment: smartmeet@Anonymus:~$ traceroute google.com
The program 'traceroute' can be found in the following packages:
 * inetutils-traceroute
 * traceroute
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: @ThatGuy smartmeet@Anonymus:~$ traceroute google.com
The program 'traceroute' can be found in the following packages:
 * inetutils-traceroute
 * traceroute
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
smartmeet@Anonymus:~$ sudo apt-get install traceroute
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package traceroute is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'traceroute' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say what could be the problem, but tell you what you can try to detect it:

1. Connect another device to the router. If it works, the router seems fine.
2. If you have wired connection, try changing the wire. If you have wireless connection, try changing the wireless device or connecting via Ethernet (wired). You can also try that wire in other devices that you know work fine. If these things (wire or wireless device) work in other devices, they are fine.
3. Check if your system detects the ports properly (USB, Ethernet, ...) and if you have their drivers installed. If you have, they are fine.
4. Try booting up from a LiveCD of your Linux distro and connecting to the router/Internet. If it works, the problem actually is in your installed system.
5. Check your networking configuration parameters (address, mask, gateway, ...). Your netmask is type B (`16 bits` = `255.255.0.0` by default, be careful).
6. Try "completely-uninstalling & reinstalling" the network manager to purge the current configuration and try with a fresh one.
7. And, finally, if the step 5 (LiveCD) worked for you, maybe you should consider reinstalling your operating system (save your "home-folder stuff" first)